# setTimout has no delay even though there are no obvious errors

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```js
function abc() {
    console.log("ok")
}

setTimeout(abc, 10000000000000000000000000000000)
```

When I run this code, it should delay the printing of ok by 10000000000000000000000000000000ms, but it instantly prints it out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is executed your code ?

Comment: Is there some reason you really want to set a timer for 316,880,878,140,289,450,000 ***years*** from now?!?!

Answer (score 6):

Because there's a maximum value you can use which is `2,147,483,647`

Anything above that will execute immediately

> Browsers store the delay as a 32-bit signed integer internally. This causes an integer overflow when using delays larger than 2,147,483,647 ms (about 24.8 days), resulting in the timeout being executed immediately.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#maximum_delay_value

Comment: Nice one. I'd gotten there by theorizing and experimenting (having somehow missed it in the MDN docs). Surprising that's not documented [in the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#timer-initialisation-steps).

Comment: Yah I was also looking there. Could it be depend on the engine implementation so maybe that's why its not in the standards ?

Comment: It certainly could, but since all the major implementations do the same thing (I just checked Chromium, Firefox, Safari, Node.js, and Deno), they'd normally fold it into the spec.

Comment: i tried 10 and it did not work